# Adding currency format in excel export using NPOI dll - not working

Tags: c#, npoi

I am exporting data in excel file using NPOI dll.

The data is of amount type that has to be shown in money format: $#,###.##
and also in date format.

I've added the format to the cells. but the data is not exporting to Excel as a Money/date format

Any answers for it?

here is my code:

I've tried all the kinds of currecy formats that I found in Google search but nothing worked,
it still exporting to Excel as a text and not a currency / date type

```
public enum StyleDataTypes { NotDeclared = 0, Money = 1, Percentage = 2, Number = 3, Date = 4 }

     public class ColumnInfoAttribute : Attribute


 {


    private string displayNoValue = "";

    public string DisplayNoValue
    {
        get { return displayNoValue; }
        set { displayNoValue = value; }
    }

    private StyleDataTypes styleType = StyleDataTypes.NotDeclared;

    public StyleDataTypes StyleType
    {
        get { return styleType; }
        set { styleType = value; }
    }

}


IDataFormat dataFormatCustom = sheet.Workbook.CreateDataFormat();

            ICellStyle dateStyle = sheet.Workbook.CreateCellStyle(); //date
            dateStyle.DataFormat = dataFormatCustom.GetFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

            ICellStyle amountStyle = sheet.Workbook.CreateCellStyle(); //money
            amountStyle.DataFormat = dataFormatCustom.GetFormat("$#,##0.00");

  StyleDataTypes dataType = ((ColumnInfoAttribute)attr).StyleType;   
 switch (dataType)
                    {
                        case StyleDataTypes.Date:
                           cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = dateStyle.DataFormat;
                            break;
                        case StyleDataTypes.Number:
                           cell.SetCellType(CellType.Numeric);
                            break;
                        case StyleDataTypes.Percentage:
                            cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = percentagesStyle.DataFormat;
                            break;
                        case StyleDataTypes.Money:
                            cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = amountStyle.DataFormat;
                            break;
                    }
```

in the Excel field it showes as a text field and not custom as I did.

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating the DataFormat first.

Try this sample

```
ICellStyle amountStyle = sheet.Workbook.CreateCellStyle(); //money
amountStyle.DataFormat = sheet.Workbook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat(.GetFormat("$#,##0.00");
```